# Error 1114(HY000) at line 33340: The table quickbooks_log is full

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure why my original post got marked as a duplicate as None of the solutions in the supposedly duplicate post holds any relevance to my issue. 
My disk isn't full and my innodb_data_file_path hasn't been limited to 512M as the Accepted solution in that post

I've been trying to import some data into a backup Mysql server but I'm receiving the error mentioned in the title.

I'm running Mysql 5.7.18 , fresh install. Every table has it's own ibd file and innodb_data_file_path is set to ibdata1:12M:autoextend

There's also plenty of disk space left on both my /tmp directory and the drive containing the actual data. Another thing worth mentioning is that it stop importing data when the file reached exactly 4 gigabytes (4294967296)

The dump file is around 8.2GB
8740998408 May 10 19:37 fullDB.sql

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think so , the issue only seems present when I try and import data from a mysql datadump.  I can add records manually afterwards but it always seems to stop when die table reached 4GB.

Comment: Why has this been marked as a duplicate ? None of the solutions in the other post holds any relevance to my issue. My disk isn't full and my innodb_data_file_path hasn't been limited to 512M as the Accepted solution in that post.